# How to make page turning effect in Android?

Tags: android, animation, effects

Can any one tell me how to make page turn effect in Android?
Can any one please provide me some code snippet.

Comment: Do you mean so it actually looks like a page turning or just Views sliding left and right when you swipe your finger across the display?

Comment: i m expecting that,views should slide left and right when swipe fingers across the display.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [this](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=en#RzGvLIykRFs/src/com/android/calculator2/PanelSwitcher.java&q=android%20package:git://android.git.kernel.org%20Calculator2).

It's a Calculator application, which changes between normal/scientific mode on swipe gesture:

```
onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)
```

It uses `TranslateAnimation` to accomplish the effect, but dragging between the views and tracking your finger, like in the iPhone is not implemented. Try using

```
onScroll(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)
```

for that.

As for [Flexbook](http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/book/Anatomy.html)-like component, it shouldn't be hard to implement, if you use the masking approach.

Android M3 (pre-1.0 version) even had PageTurner widget, but it got deprecated, since it wasn't generic-enough, like the other widgets. You can try and dig up the old Android sources to find the implementation of PageTurner and modify it for Cupcake/Donut.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately Google Code Search was shut down. Here's another location of the component: http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_calculator/blobs/42d696406d2e83c3cbb1bd424ed53f6676121e8f/src/com/android/calculator2/PanelSwitcher.java