# Android Touch scroll animation for Page flip

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to implement a View which has five children, but only one is visible. When the user touch scrolls from right to left or left to right, the next or previous view should appear in sync with the scroll. If the touch is finished and scroll distance did not exceed a given distance, then then the new view which is partly shown should go back and the current view should be shown. If the touch is finished and scroll distance has exceeded a given distance, then new view should come & current view should go. I tried with viewflipper, but it has only showNext() & showPrevious() through which the new view can not be shown on sync with the scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Pavan here is a similar question [page curl turn effect in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376962/page-curl-turn-effect-in-android)

and also you may give try  to [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

**EDIT:**
Just found theses linked posts

[how to make page turning effect in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523784/how-to-make-page-turning-effect-in-android#)

[android page curl animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015586/android-page-curl-animation)

and also [this code](http://www.gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_calculator/blobs/42d696406d2e83c3cbb1bd424ed53f6676121e8f/src/com/android/calculator2/PanelSwitcher.java).

Comment: Thank you. I will go through it.