# How to turn the page

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android page Curl animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015586/android-page-curl-animation)

i want to do turn the page effect,i want the page http://www2.parc.com/istl/groups/uir/publications/items/UIR-2004-10-Hong-DeformingPages.pdf

but i cannot how to use,can you give me some advice

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523784/how-to-make-page-turning-effect-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376962/page-curl-turn-effect-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015586/android-page-curl-animation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908739/android-page-curl-animation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839117/how-to-do-page-flip-turn-curl-effect-in-android

Comment: yes,i found the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android is more useful,thank you